How to display a list of users on the Windows Server 2025 lockscreen?
You can see all the local users that can be switched on the lockscreen of Windows 11:
However, on the lockscreen of Windows Server 2025, a username and password must be entered, and there is no listing of user options that you can choose to switch to:
So isn't there a way to display a list of users on the lockscreen of a Server system? Like in Windows 11?
